# vue bind class does not update

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

```
<div id="nav">
    <div v-bind:class="['staticClass', { 'show' : visible }]"></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
var nav = new Vue({
    el: '#nav',
    data: {
        visible: false
    }
});

document.getElementById('hamburger', addEventListener('click', function(){
    nav.visible = !nav.visible;
}
```

It works initially. class 'show' is only added if visible is true. And nav.visible changes properly when clicking on 'hamburger' but the class binding doesn't update. 'Show' class doesn't get added or removed after the page is created regardless of nav.visible value. Any idea why?

Comment: why are you combining regular javascript click listeners with vue.js

Comment: Use `@click` on an element to trigger a method call.

Comment: After fixing the obvious syntax errors, I [cannot reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrn9c4jw/). Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @str Don't you think this https://jsfiddle.net/9rs0e5yv/ would be even better?

Comment: @QuentinAlbert It depends. Vue.js is "incrementally adoptable" and this might be a case where exactly that is done.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const nav = new Vue({
    el: '#nav',
    data: {
      visible: false
    },
    methods: {
      toggleClass() {
        this.visible = !this.visible  
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.staticClass {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
    <button @click="toggleClass">hamburger</button>
    <div 
      v-bind:class="['staticClass', { 'show' : visible }]">
      foo
    </div>
</div>
```